# Excel filter function

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of unique items which appear multiple times in my main dataset. I would like to retrieve all the full line items in my main dataset related to the items in my list

For example:

List items:

```
John
James
Andy
Mary
```

Dataset:

```
Name    Age     Height    Gender
John    32      177       M
James   28      165       M
Andy    20      180       M
John    32      177       M
John    32      177       M
Andy    20      180       M
Mary    25      155       F
```

The above is obviously just an example. My desired output is that for the "John" item in my list I would like to retrieve all the 3 full line items related to John.

I have tried using the filter formula, which works but when I try dragging it down I get a spill error. I have 610 unique items in my list which translate to 3116 line items in my dataset.

Please advise if more info is required. I do not mind if the solution is an excel formula or VBA

Thanks!

Comment: Is what you're describing not just a sort of the dataset, in order of the list?

Comment: `=FILTER(C3:F9,ISNUMBER(FIND(C3:C9,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A2:A4))))` where C3:F9 is your dataset and A2:A4 is your List Items.

Comment: I am not exactly sure I follow what you're saying. The total dataset includes 10 000 items, I just want to extract the full line items which match the names in my list. But if the dataset can be sorted by the items in my list and I can easily identify them then that works too

Comment: As for the spill error, dragging down isn't done with the Filter formula since you're receiving a whole array back. Also, how are you expecting to retrieve/update your sheet with a given list?

Comment: I think what @CLR was getting at is that your List Items include all names that are in your Dataset so why not just sort the dataset.

Comment: How could I go about sorting the entire dataset based on my list? I don't actually have names - that was just an example. It is a list of around 600 codes

Comment: using VBA I assumed I could just write code to do an autofilter, i.e. filter for each item in my list in the main dataset and then copy and paste the filtered items somewhere. and do that for each item in the list. could this not work?

Comment: Did the formula I gave not work?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I tried it now but it just retrieves a zero value. This is an example of the actual items in my list "H2OD-5000999.21.01".

Comment: Hard to tell why it didn't work without actual data.  The first reference in the `FIND` function is looking at just the Name column in the dataset - would give a #VALUE! error rather than zero value if it's looking at the whole dataset though.

Comment: Did you adjust the ranges in the formula Darren gave, @Saadiq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem using VBA:

```vb
Sub Filter()
    Dim list As Variant

    With Sheet3
        list = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Value
        list = Application.Transpose(list)
    End With
    
    Sheet2.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=list, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

This auto filters the main dataset with all the items from the list, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=FILTER($D$4:$F$10,$C$4:$C$10=I2)
```

Fill Formula in Rows J3 & Trigger in Rows I2

Answer (score 0):

### Filter Data

**Filtered (Same Order)**

[image]

```
=LET(sData,Sheet1!A2:D8,sCol,1,cData,Sheet2!A2:A5,
    sc,CHOOSECOLS(sData,sCol),cc,TOCOL(cData,3),
    fi,FILTER(sData,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(sc,cc))),
fi)
```

**Sorted By (Grouped)**

[image]

```
=LET(sData,Sheet1!A2:D8,sCol,1,cData,Sheet2!A2:A5,
    sc,CHOOSECOLS(sData,sCol),cc,TOCOL(cData,3),
    fi,FILTER(sData,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(sc,cc))),
    sb,SORTBY(fi,XMATCH(CHOOSECOLS(fi,sCol),cc)),
sb)
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use `LET(a;FILTER(A:A;A:A<>"");FILTER(a;a<>"Nanes"))` for "cData" so the formula doesn't need adjusting when adjusting the list?

Comment: @Notus_Panda I don't like it but if it doesn't slow down the worksheet, why not. I prefer to put the data in a structured table when I can use `Let(...,cData,Table1[Names],...)`.

Comment: That is of course a better alternative, yes, thanks!